# Three.js - what do the matrices in a 3D object represent

Tags: matrix, 3d, three.js

Looking at the source of THREE.Object3D, there are three properties: `matrix`, `matrixWorld` and `matrixRotationWorld`.

I see that the object's position, scale and rotation can be extracted from `matrix`. I also see that the world position of a point on the object can be extracted from `matrixWorld`.

My question:

- Do `matrix` and `matrixWorld` represent the same information, i.e. can matrix be converted to matrixWorld, and vice versa?
- What does matrixRotationWorld represent? What is it used for? And can it be converted to `matrix` and/or `matrixWorld`?

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`object.matrix` is the matrix transform of the object.

`object.matrixWorld` is the matrix transform of the object, taking into consideration the matrix transform of the object's parent. (The object's parent may also have a parent, so the calculation of `object.matrixWorld` is recursive.)

`object.matrix` and `object.matrixWorld` are identical when the object has no parent, other than the scene.

`object.matrixRotationWorld` no longer exists.

three.js r.69